# How does cv::imencode read an image?

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a question about the [cv::imencode](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-alpha/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html#imencode) function.

It says here that it encodes an image into a buffer. I understood that the result is an array of [0, 255] value. Is that correct? Let's say it's a grayscale image to simplify.

Assuming my picture is represented by this grid:

[image]

If I would draw an arrow representing the order in which the pixel are read by the cv::imencode function, what would be the result?

Comment: "The function compresses the image and stores it in the memory buffer that is resized to fit the result. See imwrite() for the list of supported formats and flags description."  That is to say the output is bytes that represent the image in some format such as JPEG.  You can then write this output to a file.  It is hard to say what order the pixels would be read in from the input image.  This may depend on the compression method used.  In the end, it won't matter anyways.  Why do you think it matters?

Comment: It's for my homework. I need to read the pixels in a particular order. I don't know if the order mentionned in the assignment (row by row) is the default reading order or if I need to tweak something.

Comment: I'm not sure you need to use cv::imencode.  Do you mean you just need to access the image as a pointer to the data?  In that case, cv::Mat::data is a pointer to the beginning of the image data, while cv::Mat::step is the number of bytes in each row.  cv::Mat orders data first along channel, then columns, then rows.

Comment: So, just to double check. What is the content of a cv::Mat? Could you give me an exemple for the image I posted?

Comment: The contents of a cv::Mat is the image as a 3d array of values.  Check here from some more info: http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-alpha/doc/user_guide/ug_mat.html.

Comment: Ok, I guess my question was more about cv::imread than cv::imencode.

Answer (score 0):

> I understood that the result is an array of [0, 255] value. Is that correct?

Not necessarily. The format depends on the encoder. The main point of most encoders is to compress data, and the corresponding decoder decompresses the encoded data/image into the n-channel (1-channel in grayscale images) dense matrices.

See for example how this [PAM encoder](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/a92aed45a4bb0182f737a624331afcb7b0cd52a7/modules/imgcodecs/src/grfmt_pam.cpp#L694-L711) is implemented in OpenCV. That shows how to access the "raw" image data and this particular way of encoding the image.